# Error on fetching number of rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting error "Trying to get property of non-object on line 76" while executing following:

```
 require_once 'DBConnection.php' ;
$connection = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if ($connection->connect_error) die ($connection->connect_error);
$query = "Select * From product where productCategory = $productCategory";
$result = $connection->query($query);

$rows = $result->num_rows;   //line 76

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    $result->data_seek($j);

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **mysql_num_rows()** function.  For your given code, it must be like `mysql_num_rows($result)`.

You can refer PHP documentation of [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) for further details.